# Getting an SVG to Keep It's Aspect Ratio in an HTML Page

Tags: html, svg

I have HTML like that below. I create a SVG with a viewbox of 100x100. When rendered (in Chrome) The svg is rendering itself as 200px wide (good) but ~500px high and the text is pushed off the bottom of the page. Making my window bigger or smaller has no affect - the SVG simply grows or shrinks in height accordingly.

Why is the svg not constrained in height in any way? Is there a way to make it automatically keep it's 1:1 aspect ratio? The content *inside* of the SVG is fine - it scales appropriately. This is causing some major headaches

```
<html>
  <head>
    <title>SVG Ahoy</title>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  </head>
  <body>
    <div style="width: 200px;">
      <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 100 100" 
          preserveAspectRatio="xMinYMin meet" version="1.1"></svg>
      <div>content below</div>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have prserveApsectRatio set here, but I do not see a height on your div. Is that causing an issue?Also, if you look at the svg documentation, svg items **default to 100% width and height**. Try setting it's height and widths explicitly as pixel values and see if that helps.

Comment: This is what I am thinking, but I want this item to be able to scale flexibly. That is, if the window is resized, I'd like the svg to scale with it. Is this possible?

Comment: It is! I recommend schooling yourself in how percentage values work, and in more complex cases how to use Javascript or Jquery to provide finer tuning of your display of items.

Be sure to figure out what percentage of the window you want it to take up vertically. % values for heights in HTML require that their parent containers also have a height specified (keep that in mind!!). It caused unending headache for me in the past. I suggest doing a little research on dynamic height scaling in HTML or something similar (it's more of a tutorial type answer than something we could say in a forum).

Comment: Yeah, this is what I was afraid of. I'm using Backbone to do some sophisticated DOM building. At the time the SVG is first created, it doesn't know it's final width. I've created a jQuery window.resize callback to force height=width, but I was hoping that there was a good non-javascript solution.

Comment: Mmmm.... as far as understanding the height of an object in HTML you're going to be talking about requiring the entire parent-tree to have set height values (or at least the top-level parent, I think).

Comment: Yup. I was hoping maybe, with the viewbox setting, the SVG could know that it should maintain a certain aspect ratio, much the way images do. Oh well, thanks for the advice!

Answer (score 0):

Put the svg in an `<img>` tag: `<img src="path_to_svg" />`

Style the image: {width: 100%; height: auto;}

Setting the height to auto is the secret. Like this, even the preserveAspectRatio attribute is optional. (Putting it into a table layout will break Internet Explorer compatability).

Comment: Height to auto solves the problem, but there's certainly no reason to put the SVG in an image tag.  Leaving it in `<svg>` is just fine.